# How Do I Generate A Valid Cookie

Tags: cookies, postman, api-design

Using Postman, I can create an API call which creates a TWEx2 cookie and auth. The cookie will look something similar to this:

> 83df910f-86a0-4ce8-a334-696d8g0f07db

Obviously, in my production code I cannot use Postman, so I have been trying to find a way to generate these cookies on my own. But when I try to search for "TWEx2 Cookie", or any kind of generator, I find tons of recipes for Twix Cookies. Clearly that's less than helpful.

Below you will see the TWEx2 cookie, and the auth. I have found that the auth is not needed, but the cookie is. I have tried several methods without the cookie, and the API request results in NULL.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on some instructions on how to create these hashed strings, or explain it to me?

Comment: Where did you see the term `TWEx2` in the first place? That string is just a UUID/GUID, it's most likely a database record pointer (but unpredictable for security purposes).

Comment: If it isn't for your own web-service then you cannot create your own cookies for it because that would mean you'd have broken their security. What are you **actually** trying to do here?

Comment: This is for my own web service. I am trying to make an API call which, for some unknown reason, doesn't seem to want to work unless it has a cookie. I'll see if I can upload a picture to the post to show you where I am seeing it.

Comment: I don't understand how, if it's your own web-service, you don't understand how your own cookies work.

Comment: The rest of the `TWExAuth` cookie looks like an encrypted binary blob (with inefficient Base16 encoding instead of Base64 or Base85). The initial bytes (`0xDCF0E88154`) do not correspond to any plaintext or human-readable token structures (like JWT or SAML)

Comment: Knowing how cookies work, and knowing how to create a cookie for a specific service is not quite the same thing. The API is not mine, but the service calling the API is.

Comment: It does certainly look like a UUID - it's the same format. But I thought maybe the TWEx2 might have a specific way to generate it.

Comment: "The API is not mine" - that's what I was asking you originally

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was my headers - I thought that I had accepted all returned values from the API but I had left out 'CURLOPT_HEADER' from my cURL.

Without receiving a cookie from the API, I had assumed (incorrectly) that I needed to create my own cookie. As soon as I added that in the header, I was able to see the cookie which was generated and returned by the API and use that.

So, if you run into this problem, make sure your headers are correct.

As a side note, "TWEx2" appears to be something specific to this API. It does not appear to be a normal thing.